# How to re-load whole page (without response.redirect)?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

How can I reload the whole page without using `Response.Redirect`?

Based on the user, my page (Mypage.aspx) is loading with some data in it. After the user changes some fields and if the user clicks the save button, the code needs to save that changed data; or if the user clicks on the cancel button, the code should reload the user's previous data (by reloading the Mypage.aspx page).

I'm using an update panel in this page. How is this possible without doing a client redirect to the same page? I don't want to redirect because Mypage.aspx contains different controls like grid views, dropdowns, checkboxes, and textboxes; if I wrote code to clear all those fields, it would become somewhat lengthy code. So I'm looking for another way to do this.

Comment: Provide properties and methods that you can call. For example a `BindData(int id)` where you load the data and `DataBind` your controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of `Response.Redirect()`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", "window.location.href='Mypage.aspx';", true);
```